# Select IF a dos campos de dos tablas SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas en SQL SERVER 2014, y estan relacionadas por un id, ahora sucede que si en una tabla el campo Aprobado dice la palabara "NO" entonces en el campo Estatus de la otra tabla debe decir "NO" y asi etc, aquí dejo mi consulta (creo que si se entiende bien), el caso es que esta sintaxis no es correcta y quisiera saber cual es la manera de lograr esto.
Gracias

```html
select F.Id, A.Nombre, F.Fecha,
(CASE WHEN F.Aprobado isNull then 'NO' 
else case when E.Estatus IsNull then F.Aprobado='NO' 
else case when E.Estatus='NO' THEN F.Aprobado='NO'
ELSE CASE WHEN E.Estatus='SI' THEN F.Aprobado='SI' END) as Aprobado 

from finan F 
LEFT JOIN AgenA on F.IdAgn=A.IdAgn 
left join TEstatus E ON E.Id=F.Id
ORDER BY FECHA DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas usar `IS NULL` en vez de `ISNULL`. El primero es una comparación, el segundo es el nombre de una función.

Comment: También falta una coma entre nombre y fecha.

Comment: @LuisCazares ya lo edite

Comment: Tras el THEN no puede ir una comparación, debes poner un resultado, en tu caso entiendo que pones 'NO'. Tras y como tienes en el primer WHEN.

Comment: La construcción del `CASE` está mal. Podría ser algo así: `CASE WHEN F.Aprobado IS NULL then 'NO' WHEN E.Estatus IS NULL THEN 'NO' WHEN E.Estatus='NO' THEN 'NO' ELSE 'SI' END`

Comment: @M.Nacher si entiendo lo que me dice, y se que esta sintaxis no es correcta y quisiera saber cual es la manera de lograr esto que explico, porque necesito saber lo que hay en un campo para poder ponerle el resultado al otro, por eso mi duda, de que otra manera se podria hacer

Comment: @PatricioMoracho es correcto gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podemos revisar un poco la sintaxis del CASE. CASE es una expresión y por lo tanto debe regresar un valor y no ejecutar una acción. El valor regresado por CASE debe ser del mismo tipo para todos los casos. Podemos simplificar la expresión tomando el único caso que regresará un 'Sí' y dejar los demás casos como ELSE.

```
SELECT F.Id, 
    A.Nombre, 
    F.Fecha,
    CASE WHEN E.Estatus = 'SI' THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END as Aprobado 
FROM finan F 
LEFT JOIN AgenA      ON F.IdAgn = A.IdAgn 
LEFT JOIN TEstatus E ON E.Id = F.Id
ORDER BY FECHA DESC;
```

Recuerda que CASE funciona como un SWITCH más que como un IF. Por lo tanto, puede tener distintas condiciones. Antes de simplificarlo, hubiera quedado de la siquiente forma.

```
CASE WHEN F.Aprobado IS NULL THEN 'NO' 
    WHEN E.Estatus IS NULL THEN 'NO' 
    WHEN E.Estatus = 'NO' THEN 'NO'
    WHEN E.Estatus = 'SI' THEN'SI' END as Aprobado
```